# loading arrays of URL into UIWebView using plist

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any ways to load an arrays of `String` into `URL` to be loaded in `UIWebview`? I am using `plist` to get the values. My incorrect code to retrieve the value is

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "BOITLIST", ofType: "plist") {
  let dictRoot = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
  if let dict = dictRoot {
    let userEnteredData = dict["webURL"] as! [String]
    let url = URL(string: userEnteredData)
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:url!))
  }
}
```

and my plist looks like

[image]

The menu items 1-7 are the side menus i made. I would like to show the different loads from the `URL` when I click on each Menu Items

Comment: you will get error on this line, let url = URL(string: userEnteredData). Since,   userEnteredData is an array. It is expecting a url string.

Comment: yes, that's my error. Is there any ways for me to load an array of URL into UIWebview?

Comment: let url = URL(string: userEnteredData[0]) for the first url stiring

Comment: ok, and the other url strings? may i know how should i declare them so that when I click on my side bar menus, each different menu titles i click, i would be able to load different URLs which i set in the plist?

Comment: you can get the url string from the array, 'userEnteredData' based on the side menu index.